# Python Extract variable data from lines

Tags: python, string, extract

I need to extract several pieces of data from an HTML file into an excel sheet. I have pulled the data, now I just need to extract it from the lines. Here is an example:

```
"501.92secs: iPhone 5s_DownStream HTTP_TCP_Downlink_1 : ILOAD = **12.000** Mbps OLOAD = **4.999** Mbps FRATE = 4.980 Mbps L4 Goodput = 4.788 Mbps Packet Loss = 0.38 SLA Result = **FAIL**<font color=white>"
```

I have put in bold the items I need to extract. Because these values change every with every file and they need to be saved to a variable name, I don't really know where to start.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start with string.split() and go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is a hacky answer... It doesn't look pretty but if your string pattern remains the same, you should be able to get the results.

```
string = "501.92secs: iPhone 5s_DownStream HTTP_TCP_Downlink_1 : ILOAD = **12.000** Mbps OLOAD = **4.999** Mbps FRATE = 4.980 Mbps L4 Goodput = 4.788 Mbps Packet Loss = 0.38 SLA Result = **FAIL**<font color=white>"


import re
def getnumbers(string,patterns):
 results = []
 for pattern,number in patterns.items():
    match = re.search(pattern,string)
    valuestart = match.span()[1]
    results.append([pattern,(string[valuestart+3:valuestart+number+3])])
 return results

#If you need obtain more values, add them to the dictionary in the argument.
#The number next to each pattern indicates the expected size of the result. 
print(getnumbers(string,{"ILOAD =":7,"OLOAD =":7,"Result =":4})) #[['Result =', 'FAIL'], ['OLOAD =', '4.999**'], ['ILOAD =', '12.000*']]
```